# SQL server perform date conversion before querying

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I  have an application which returns the date in the format: "Thu Sep 22 2016" and I want to query sql server database which has stored
the date in the format "2016-09-06". Does SQL server provide any built-in function for conversion (specially the 3 letter month name to number)?
Please let me know.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp - might be useful?

Comment: In your application stack always convert your string representation to a DateTime instance as early as possible when calling in. When calling out always convert back to a string as late as possible. Ideally both conversions occur in the presentation layer. Based on this best practice the datetime should be stored as an actual date time, your app should have converted your string value to a date time which makes creating a query simple as you are comparing like types.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. But unfortunately I do not have control over that application returning the date - It is basically the date output obtained by executing a zfs command. It is returned by the filesystem

Comment: How many times are you going to ask the same question?

Comment: Apologies, but the other question was to convert the date format in shell script as per desired format and pass to the SQL server and this one intended to check for a solution in the sql server query. Thanks to inputs from all, now I have both the solutions, and I can pick the best suitable.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has limited date conversion support. These are described in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

I think this does what you want:

```
select convert(date, substring(col, 5, 6) + ',' + right(col, 5), 107)
```

The idea is to convert your string to "Sep 22, 2016" and then use this for the conversion.  Assuming your internationalization formats are set to English, then this approach should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)

Example:

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME = '10/01/2011';  
SELECT FORMAT ( @d, 'd', 'en-US' ) AS 'US English Result'  
      ,FORMAT ( @d, 'd', 'en-gb' ) AS 'Great Britain English Result'  
      ,FORMAT ( @d, 'd', 'de-de' ) AS 'German Result'  
      ,FORMAT ( @d, 'd', 'zh-cn' ) AS 'Simplified Chinese (PRC) Result';   

SELECT FORMAT ( @d, 'D', 'en-US' ) AS 'US English Result'  
      ,FORMAT ( @d, 'D', 'en-gb' ) AS 'Great Britain English Result'  
      ,FORMAT ( @d, 'D', 'de-de' ) AS 'German Result'  
      ,FORMAT ( @d, 'D', 'zh-cn' ) AS 'Chinese (Simplified PRC) Result';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('Sep 22, 2016','%M %d,%Y');
```

Comment: Getting error "'STR_TO_DATE' is not a recognized built-in function name.
"

Comment: Which version you are using mysql?

Comment: @TK the question says: "*Does **SQL server** provide any built-in function for conversion*"

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you have to do is to remove the day of the week part of your string date format. Once that is removed, the string is in a standard date format for SQL Server.

```
Declare @yourTable table (
    Id int identity(1,1),
    YourDate  datetime2
)

Insert into @yourTable values 
('2016-09-22'),
('2016-09-16'),
('2016-09-22')

Declare @appDate varchar(100) = 'Thu Sep 22 2016'
Set @appDate = ltrim(substring(@appDate,4,len(@appDate)-3))
select * from @yourTable where cast(YourDate as date) = @appDate
```

I also converted the datetime in the table to date to avoid using the time component of the datetime when querying.